# Show only Top 1 value based on Key

Tags: sql, distinct

I need to show only the Top 1 Value of a Grandtotal based on a Key Field,The remaining should be printed as null,

As you see below for single Document no i have to show only one grand total and the second one should be show as NULL.

```
DOCUMENTNO  TOTAL      DELIVERYCHARGE   GRANDTOTAL
BR17000079  59878.80       0.00          132639.52
BR17000079  59878.80       0.00          132639.52
```

If anyone have idea ,Please help me to fix this.

Thanks,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, there is no "first" or "second" row -- unless a column specifies the ordering.  The columns that you have shown all have the same value, so there is no "first".

You can set *one* of the values to `NULL`:

```
select t.DOCUMENTNO, t.TOTAL, t.DELIVERYCHARGE
       (case when row_number() over (partition by t.DOCUMENTNO order by t.DOCUMENTNO) = 1
             then GRANDTOTAL
        end) as GRANDTOTAL
from t;
```